# How to calculate AUC for a P-R curve with unusual starting point

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, auc, precision-recall

I am working with a binary classifier that is outputting scores between 0 and 1, indicating probabilities of class membership, according to the model. I produced a P-R curve and the first point (i.e., threshold=1) is (0.49, 0.62), shown in the figure below.
[image]

I am unsure about how to compute the AUC for this curve. According to scikit-learn convention, I can add the (0, 1) point, but then I just get a (false) diagonal line from (0, 1) to (0.49, 0.62), which seems untrue. What is the advice to deal with such a curve?